# Angular JS Directive scope.$watch into Angular 6

Tags: angular6

```
    In angular 1, The code was written like this.


**AngularJS**:

    scope.$watch('hiddenScroll', () => {
              $timeout(this.updateFadersVisibility());
            });



    **Angular 6**

    ngOnChanges(changes: any) {
      setTimeout(() => {
          this.updateFadersVisibility();
        }, 1000);
      }
```

I am looking for a better solution. ngOnChanges are not working as expected.

Comment: what kind of variable is hiddenScroll?

Comment: In angular 1  scope: {
    hiddenScroll: '=',
   },

Comment: @UdayaVani the onchanges lifecycle hook only works with one-way bindings

Comment: @tcrite, then how to make this as a two way data bindings?